# Landsat 1MSS composite colour

Tags: landsat

How can we match the Landsat 1 MSS and Landsat TM, ETM + and OLI bands?

I have a scene of 1973, but on this one, there are only the bands 4, 5, 6, 7 and the bands T2_BQA and T2_VER, unlike the other sensors where one has the bands B1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, etc.
it is to say to make the composition colored in natural color or false color of L1 MSS

Comment: According to the [USGS](https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/landsat-1?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con) Landsat 1 MSS had green (0.5 to 0.6 µm), red (0.6 to 0.7 µm), NIR (0.7 to 0.8 µm) & NIR (0.8 to 1.1 µm) bands. So no blue band.  Use 6 (NIR), 5 (red) and 4 (green) for a false colour image, or look into how to generate a pseudo true colour image liker what people have done with SPOT 4/5 images.